# Diagonal elements of subset of Hadamard matrices

Tags: matrices, permutations

I'm looking at Sylvester's construction of Hadamard matrices, where $H_{2^n} = \left[\begin{array}{c c}
H_{2^{n-1}} & H_{2^{n-1}} \\
H_{2^{n-1}} & -H_{2^{n-1}}
\end{array}\right]$, where $H_{2^0} = [1]$.

If we take a subset of the Hadamard matrix of the form $H_S = H_{:, 1:k}$ where we look at the first $k$ columns of the matrix, then the diagonal elements of $H_S H_S^T$ are equal to $k$, and the diagonal elements of $(H_SH_S^T)^2$ are equal to $k2^n$.

I'm not sure what is the best way to show the second part, where the diagonal elements of $(H_SH_S^T)^2 = k2^n$.

Currently, I'm trying to show that all rows of $H_SH_S^T$ are a permutation of each other, and due to symmetry of $H_SH_S^T$, each diagonal element of $(H_SH_S^T)^2$ must be equal. Then since the trace of $(H_SH_S^T)^2$ is equal to $(H_S^TH_S)^2$, each diagonal entry of $(H_SH_S^T)$ must be equal to $k2^n$. However, I am not sure how to show that all rows of $H_SH_S^T$ are a permutation of each other.

Any help given would be appreciated, or hints at another method to tackle this problem. Thanks!

Solved!

Comment: you are right - edited!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

1. It helps to write the matrix multiplication for the diagonal elements of $H_S H_S^T$ in index notation. What do the resulting products in the summation look like?
2. A key property of Hadamard matrices is that $H_n^T H_n=n I_{nn}$. What about your subset matrices? Answering this makes the diagonal elements of $(H_S H_S^T)^2$ far easier to compute.

Comment: I've solved this - didn't make much use of the second hint (have done the first part so didn't need the first hint), although the outline of my solution might be what you've intended. Here's a sketch of my solution.

Denoting $H_i$ as the $i^\text{th}$ row / column of $H$, then it is easy to see that the diagonal elements $(H_sH_s^T)^2$ must be equal to the sum of diagonal elements of $\sum_{i=1}^k (H_iH_i^T)^2$.

But each diagonal element must be equal to $$2^n$$ the diagonal elements of $(H_iH_i^T)^2$ is a sum of 1s.

Comment: @JSL I suspect we're saying the same thing, but here's my gloss on it. First, $H_S^T H_S = 2^n I_{kk}$ since any subset of the columns of $H_S$ (your $H_i$'s in particular) are mutually orthogonal. So $$(H_S H_S^T)^2=H_S(H_S^T H_S)H_S^T = 2^n H_S I_{kk} H_S^T.$$ Then the $j$-th diagonal element is $2^n \sum_{i=1}^k (H_S)_{jk}^2=2^n k$ since all elements of $H_S$ are $\pm 1$. (Which is the same argument I'd use in part 1, but with summation over $k$ elements rather than all $2^n$).